# Select and edit the text of all links in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to create a basic script which replace "." or "_" in url text in specific table of the site.

Code:

```js
$('tbody tr td:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) a').each(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var linkText = link.text();
    link.text( linkText.replace("."," ") );  
    link.text( linkText.replace("_"," ") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class="category">
   <img src="image.gif" data-original="image.gif"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="filename">
   <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
    <a href="link" class="link-class">VMware.Workstation.v11.1.2</a>
   </div>    
  </td>        
 </tr>             
 <tr>
  <td class="category">
   <img src="image.gif" data-original="image.gif"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="filename">
   <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
    <a href="link" class="link-class">ADOBE_AFTEREFFECTS_CC_V2015</a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

But It's not working correctly. Work only with the first text manipulation and replace only the first "." or "_" not all in the whole string.

For example:

"VMware.Workstation.v11.1.2" => "VMware Workstation.v11.1.2" - removes only first dot

What I need is

"ADOBE_AFTEREFFECTS_CC_V2015" => "ADOBE AFTEREFFECTS CC V2015" and

"VMware Workstation.v11.1.2" => "VMware Workstation v11.1.2"

hmm and is there a way to notremoving dot after string starting with v(because of version v11.1.2).

I will be glad if you help me tocreate this script and if there is a better way to select this table / links and edit their text would be wonderful.

**EDIT**

I'm almost ready but this regex is....

```
/([\.\-\_])(?![\v\d])/g
```

Link: http://regexr.com/3b7n6

Answer (score 0):

`replace` takes a regular expression as the first argument. You need to add a `g` at the end to make it greedy so it replaces all of the matches. You can translate your code to:

```
link.text( linkText.replace(/\./g," ") );  
link.text( linkText.replace(/_/g," ") );
```

You can also combine it to one `replace` call like so:

```
link.text( linkText.replace(/[._]/g," ") );
```

You can think of `[]` as a box of one character matches that contains `.` and `_`.

MDN: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a global replace.

`link.text( linkText.replace(/\./g," ") );
link.text( linkText.replace(/_/g," ") );`

Answer (score 0):

For one there is no `div:nth-child(2)` in your code anywhere so you need to replace that with `div` as there is only one div child.

And to replace the characters you can use this simple regex.

```
$('tbody tr td:nth-child(2) div a').each(function() {
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/\.|_/g," ") );
});
```

Which means `replace all occurrences of '.' and '_' with ' ' in the current string`

Also, you need the `tbody` to be within a `table` for it to work correctly. Otherwise jQuery will not see `tbody`.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ap2o3fow/2/))